# I can't catch c++ exceptions

Tags: c++, exception, cmake

I can not catch exceptions for some reason. When I try, program crashes with trace trap. I use m1 macbook, clang 17 and cmake 3.28 (I tried other versions and it doesn't work either). I tried reproducing this wierd thing on a smaler scale and it still doesn't work for me.
Here it is

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)
project(doesntwork VERSION 0.0.0.1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

add_executable(test except.cpp othertu.cpp)
```

except.cpp (main function)

```
#include <print>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "otherheader.h"

int main() {
  try {
    int x = 0;
    std::cin >> x;
    magic ma(x);
  } catch (std::runtime_error const& e) {
    std::println("{}", e.what());
  }
}
```

otherheader.h

```
#include <print>

void maythrow();

class magic{
  public:
  magic(int x);
};
```

othertu.cpp

```
#include "otherheader.h"

void maythrow() {
  // there is no file test.txt so this function is meant to always throw
  //I did this in case compiler decides to optimize away everything
  std::ifstream file{"test.txt", std::ios::binary};
  if (file) {
    std::println("good");
  } else {
    throw std::runtime_error{"bad"};
  }
}

magic::magic(int x) {
  if (x > 1) {
      maythrow();
  }
}
```

I provided cmake file because for some reason this weird thing occured while using cmake. If I simply do  `clang++ -std=c++23 except.cpp othertu.cpp` then it works as it should. And I have no clue why. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: works as it should means that maythrow function throws an exceptions which is then caught in main and program prints out `bad`
in cmake case I get trace trap and nothing is printed.

Edit 2: I wrestled with it for a bit and still have no clue. I changed compiler to apple clang and it didn't work as well, but what did work is gcc. So I just switched to gcc for my project

Comment: Do you see `good` in cmake version ?

Comment: Since there is a file check that depends on environment. Suggest to make it always throw and check what will happen. Or provide a [mre] in godbolt.org

Comment: Oh I didn't explain what I tried to do well enoguh. I am sorry. There is no file "test.txt" so that function allways throws and the result should always be ```bad```, but in cmake case it traps and nothing is shown at all . I did this file thingy in case compiler decides to omptimize away something

Comment: @suspiciously_large_carrot All that needs to go into the question. Please edit it.

Comment: Does clang 17 support `<print>`? I got error in godbolt. So I removed print header and use std::cout instead. It seems fine [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zjG81o716). `bad` is printed. Your example doesn't compile, I had to add `ifstream` header in othertu.cpp. Please confirm you have a [mre]. (Use my godbolt link as a template)

Comment: @LouisGo print certainly works with clang 17(cppreference says about partial support). And it works as it should when I compile with clang++. It just doesn't work with cmake for me. The problem probably lies with my computer but I have no way to verify it. I feel so defeated

Comment: It seems like a cmake issue other than C++ issue. You need to fix the config with compilation errors. I haven't touched cmake for a while.

Comment: `project(doesntwork VERSION 0.0.0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)`

Comment: 1. Please show *exactly* what you saw when you decided that "program crashes with trace trap". 2. Do `make clean && make VERBOSE=1`, examine the output for obvious errors.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI 1. zsh: trace trap. that's all there was. 2. I spent a good few hours doing this and couldn't see anything wrong. 
anyway I just nuked everything and switched compilers, which seems to work. I don't want to deal with this anymore

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how I solved it(it is disapointing to call that a solution tho) the answer is at the end.

Ok so I still don't have a concrete reason. But here is what I found out:

This problem appeared after I installed normal clang 17 (before I used Apple clang). It appears not always but in very concrete circumstances. Those are

- You need to utilize raii capabilities after exception is thrown e.g. you need to destruct fstream object, like in my example. If fstream object is destructed before exception is thrown then there is no problem.
- You have more than one translation unit. If it is in one file it works as it should. I guess that's the reason why using -flto helps sometimes.

Interestingly, switching back to apple clang also seems to not work. As it has the same issue. Switching to gcc made it work.

I have no proof of what I am about to say, this is just my speculation after a few days of hairpulling. It seems after I installed llvm and started using it, there appeared internal confusion and some components were used from normal clang, and some were used from apple clang. Since those are very similar there were no issues most of the time, but in some specific circumstances some differences appeared and caused this unexpected behaviour. The issue most likely was during linking stage.

So I solved it by uninstalling normal llvm. After I did it, apple clang started working again. This was probably my mess up somewhere along the installation process but I have no desire nor enough knowledge to dig any deeper.

Comment: It's better to provide a reproducible repo or godbolt to show your result. Also started working again after uninstalling llvm seems like a mixed of library in compilation time. Indicating the compilation might lookup the mixed std libs ..etc Anything could happen. You should hint cmake to use a specific compiler to rule out this issue. If you need further clarification, elaborate everything you've done in the question but not just "several hours of work"..